# Scan a elementos anidados - DynamoDB

Tags: nosql, cli, dynamodb

Amig@s, tengo la siguiente duda. Necesito realizar una consulta la cual debe traerme sólo los registros dada una condición - *equivalente a un Select campos From tabla Where condición* en SQL -.

La estructura de la tabla es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta la estoy haciendo mediante CLI de esta manera

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name chats-ejecutivo --no-paginate --filter-expression "#phone = :phone" --expression-attribute-names '{"#phone": "user.phone"}' --expression-attribute-values '{":phone" : {"S": "56931154510"}}'
```

pero esto me devuelve el siguiente resultado, donde no encuentra coincidencias

```
{
    "Items": [],
    "Count": 0,
    "ScannedCount": 74
}
```

Agote mi fuente de conocimientos, por lo que cualquier ayuda se agradece :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución al problema. 
Si se quiere acceder a una propiedad de un objeto anidado, que en mi caso era **user.phone**, se debe dar un "alias" en `--expression-attribute-names` pero sólo del objeto. La propiedad **phone** debía incluirla en `--filter-expression` de la siguiente forma

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name chats-ejecutivo --filter-expression "#u.phone = :phone" --expression-attribute-names '{"#u": "user"}' --expression-attribute-values '{":phone" : {"S": "56931154510"}}'
```

Asimismo si el **[tipo de dato](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html)** no es un Objeto (Map) y es un Arreglo (List) sólo se debería incluir el índice correspondiente

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name chats-ejecutivo --filter-expression "#u[0...N].phone = :p" --expression-attribute-names '{"#u": "user"}' --expression-attribute-values '{":p" : {"S": "56931154510"}}'
```

Espero a alguien le sea de utilidad =)